# Nodejs : получение количества записанных байтов от writeSync

Tags: node.js

Делаю все синхронно - открываю синхронно, читаю синхронно... Стал записывать синхронно - не могу получить количество записанных байтов.
Функция `writeSync` должна по документации возвращать количество записанных байтов.
Вместо этого в переменной `[object fsReqWrap]` - пусто

```html
var ttt=fs.writeSync(fd ,text + "\r\n", startpos, 'utf8');
```

Можно прикрепить к ней callback и получить количество записанных данных - но это уже будет асинхронно.
А как все таки получить синхронно?